# logging inside a forkIO/catch block

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, io-monad

I am building a servant app that generates reports using shake started by GETting a url. Up until the request to log stuff this has worked like a charm, but now I am hitting a problem.

One handler `start` starts the generation of a report - since this might take quite some time - I return 200 immediately, and spawn a process to do the real work, logging is done by [`logging-effect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logging-effect).

A simplified version of my `start` handler looks like this

```
start :: IO () -> App ()
start mkReport = do
  logInfo $ PP.text "Report generation started"
  _ <- liftIO . forkIO $ catch mkReport caught
  where caught e =  do logError $ PP.text "Report generation crashed: " <>
                     {-^^^^^^^-} (PP.text . T.pack $ displayException e)
                       cleanup
  return ()
```

`App` is an instance of `MonadLog (WithTimestamp (WithSeverity Doc))` - so `logInfo` works fine. ✔

To be precise `App` is the following newtype:

```
newtype App a =
    App { _runApp :: ReaderT Environment (ExceptT ServantErr
                     (LoggingT (WithTimestamp (WithSeverity Doc)) IO)) a
        } deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Environment,
                   , MonadError ServantErr, MonadLog (WithTimestamp (WithSeverity Doc)))
```

But when I try to call `logError` inside the `caught` part - alongside the `cleanup` action which removes generated/temporary files I get a compiler error. ✘

```
No instance for MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) IO arising from a use of 'logError'...
```

And this is correct there is no such instance for `IO`, thank you ghc for telling me that and not crashing at runtime!

These are the thoughts I am going through - maybe someone sees a false assumption:

- I have to use `forkIO` to fork the report generation?
- If there was something that works like `forkIOish :: MonadIO m => m () -> m ThreadId` and `catchIsh :: (MonadIO m, Exception e) => m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a`   would it help me? - I think yes - I could `liftIO` the cleanup and the mkReport part while calling `logError` inside `App` in my case.
- Is there a way to "unlift" properties of the monad transformer stack in the lifted parts?

Comment: This sounds like [*monad-unlift*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-unlift) (cf. the readme there), except that I believe you would have to have your `ExceptT` layer swallowed (e.g. as `IO` exceptions) in order to use it.